# After making partition, I couldn't see device (/dev/sda3)

Tags: partitioning, fdisk

I made a partiion sda3 using fdisk, but after that, I don't see /dev/sda3.

If I fdisk -l, I see this.

```
test@jylenovo:~$ sudo fdisk  -l

Disk /dev/sda: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders, total 976773168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000ded3d

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048   292968447   146483200   83  Linux
/dev/sda2       945522686   976771071    15624193    5  Extended
/dev/sda3       292968448   800000000   253515776+  83  Linux
/dev/sda5       945522688   976771071    15624192   82  Linux swap / Solaris

Partition table entries are not in disk order
```

But, I don't see /dev/sda3 like this.

```
test@jylenovo:~$ ls /dev/sda3 -l
ls: cannot access /dev/sda3: No such file or directory
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The linux kernel has not been informed you've created the partition.

Your can reboot, or use the `partprobe` command:

```
sudo partprobe
```

You don't even need to specify the disk argument. It will test all your drives for new partitions. See `man partprobe`

The `partprobe command` is in the **parted** package.